# Why has my DirectoryEntry stopped working suddenly?

Tags: binding, active-directory, directoryservices, directoryentry

I have been working with the DirectoryEntry objects in the DirectoryServices namespace and it has been going very well. But I made changes to one of my LDAP classes and all of a sudden it has stopped working on the 32 bit builds of my program.
I imported the ActiveDs reference into my project in order to convert the ADSI objects to their appropriate types. But since then my projects are failing to bind correctly when creating instances of the DirectoryEntry object.
I have tried binding with the LDAP AND WinNT provider but to no avail. The error I get is the 0x80005000 unknown error as it tries to bind.
Even this simple code fails (which is not surprising as binding is a critical part!)

```
static void Main(string[] args)  
{
    try
    {
        using(var de = new DirectoryEntry("LDAP://servername", "user", "password", AuthenticationType.Secure)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(de.Name)
        }
    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(ex)
    }
}
```

Is there any reason why this should suddenly stop working? Could a reference corrupt an already existing DLL on a 32 bit machine?
Note:
I have also tried querying LDAP using a VBS script but it just hangs.

**Results from Daro's suggestion:**
**code**

```
static void Main()
{
   try
   {
        using (var ldap = new LdapConnection(new LdapDirectoryIdentifier("ad1")))
        {
            ldap.Bind();
            using (var de = new DirectoryEntry("LDAP://" + ldap.SessionOptions.DomainName))
            {
                Console.WriteLine(de.Name);
            }
        }
    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
        using(var fs = new FileStream("C:\\error.log", FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write))
        {
            using(var sw = new StreamWriter(fs))
            {
                sw.WriteLine(ex.Message);
                sw.WriteLine(ex.StackTrace);
            }
        }
    }
```

**The log file produces:**
Unknown error (0x80005000)
   at System.DirectoryServices.DirectoryEntry.Bind(Boolean throwIfFail)
   at System.DirectoryServices.DirectoryEntry.Bind()
   at System.DirectoryServices.DirectoryEntry.get_Name()
   at Test.Program.Main() in C:\Users\#username#\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\#project#\Test\Program.cs:line 20

Answer (score 0):

Does this work for you?

```
        try
        {
            DirectoryEntry de = new DirectoryEntry("LDAP://server", "user", "password",  AuthenticationTypes.Secure);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex);
        }
```

I assume "Server" is the NetBios name?  Try using the FQDN.

If your binding with your own credentials, you can use:

```
        DirectoryEntry de = new DirectoryEntry("LDAP://server", null, null, AuthenticationTypes.Secure);
```

And if you are binding to your own domain, you could use:

```
DirectoryEntry de = new DirectoryEntry("LDAP://" + Environment.UserDomainName, null, null, AuthenticationTypes.Secure);
```

or simply:

```
DirectoryEntry de = new DirectoryEntry();
```

I hope that helps.

Comment: Any binding with the DirectoryEntry object fails. I have used IP Address and FQDN. Still nada. 

However, I can connect to Ldap if I use the LdapConnection class in the Protocols namespace.

Comment: So that bit of code I posted causes the same error?  What about:             try
            {
                LdapConnection lc = new LdapConnection(Environment.UserDomainName);
                lc.Bind();
                DirectoryEntry de = new DirectoryEntry("LDAP://" + lc.SessionOptions.DomainName);
                string Name = de.Name;
               
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(ex);
            }
Can you bind using ldp.exe?

Comment: I have been using the LdapConnection class, but whenever it needs to use a DirectoryEntry instance, it throws an exception (0x80005000) on binding.

Comment: What's the DN of the object you expect to retieve? Which is line 20? What was the change you mentioned?

Comment: Line 20 is when I am trying to get `de.Name`. It fails even if I try LDAP://RootDSE (which appears to be the starting point for the DirectoryEntry object when I peered inside the .NET code). It fails using .NET 3.5 and 4.0. 

Strang thing is, that even seperate AD browser applications are failing to connect. AD Explorer says that the server name I put in is **not a valid pathname**, but it works using my laptop!

Comment: What does "Net view YourServer" and "Net view YourServerFQDN" return or your PC and on your notebook? Do they differ?

Comment: They both return the servers full name.

Comment: What does DCDIAG /S:DomainName return, when run from your "troubled" client?  I'm afraid you're going to have to start checking the EventLog.